# What is "@get:Bindable" in the android data binding code?

Tags: android

I am new to the android data binding and I was looking at the code which says, as bellow

```
 @get:Bindable
    var userIds: MutableList<Long> = mutableListOf()
        private set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userIds)
        }
```

so, what is the `@get:Bindable` does here. Is the `@Bindable` and `@get:Bindable` same?

Comment: This kind of question you can google it.This for only problem based case.

Comment: **[Android’s Data Binding’s BaseObservable class and @Bindable annotation in Kotlin](https://medium.com/@jencisov/androids-data-binding-s-baseobservable-class-and-bindable-annotation-in-kotlin-1a5c6682a3c1)**

Answer (score 8):

### `@get:Bindable`

> In simple words, this will put `@Bindable` annotation on getter of
>   `userIds`.

Below two are identical to each other. Or you can say two ways to put annotation on getter.

```
@get:Bindable
    var userIds: MutableList<Long> = mutableListOf()
        private set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userIds)
        }

var userIds: MutableList<Long> = mutableListOf()
    @Bindable get() = _title
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userIds)
    }
```

#### For understanding more clearly in Java, it is identical to below.

```
private ArrayList<Long> userIds = new ArrayList<>();

@Bindable
public ArrayList<Long> getUserIds() {
    return userIds;
}

public void setUserIds(ArrayList<Long> userIds) {
    this.userIds = userIds;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.selected);
}
```

You can understand more about Annotations on [official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html).